# Excel formula that returns address of current (active) cell

Tags: excel

I'm trying to write an Excel formula (no VBA please) that returns the address of the active cell, i.e., the cell where the cursor is currently. For example, I have a lookup function in cell A5 that refers to lookup table with, say, 3 rows and 2 columns and I need a formula as `=vlookup(activecell, A1:B3, 2, 0)` so that when I click on, say, cell A2, then the lookup formula in cell A5 would show the contents of cell B2. I can't seem to come upon what I should use for "activecell". I've tried combinations of `row()`, `address(row(), column())`, indirect, but I can't get the magic combination. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `=CELL("address")` is updated every time a cell is edited. If they select a cell and hit delete or edit it in any way, you can use that.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for something that would refresh automatically when a user selects a cell, but it seems there's no way.

Comment: It's incredibly easy to do in VBA. By not using VBA, yea... difficult. I never understand the "I can't use VBA" requirement.

Comment: I agree, it's a slam dunk using VBA. Problem is, my users are rather elderly and some of them get antsy about the Excel warning they see when they try to open an xlsm file, even though my transmittal email assures them it's OK. The lesser of two evils, i.e., more effective solution in this particular case, is to just use the =INDIRECT(CELL("address")) approach and instruct them to click on their chosen cell (A2 in my example) and press F9 to update the helper cell (B2). Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

get current selected cell address manual(F9) or automatic
https://excel.tips.net/T002302_Displaying_the_Selected_Cells_Address.html

> **by Allen Wyatt**
>
> Excel allows you to easily see the location of the currently selected cell by examining the contents of the Name Box, to the left of the Formula Bar. This is fine and good, but there are times when you would like to have the address of a cell actually in a cell. For instance, you may want cell A1 to contain the address of the currently selected cell. This means that if cell E4 were selected, then A1 would contain its address, or $E$4. If you then pressed the right-arrow key, then the contents of A1 would change to $F$4.
>
> In order to return the address of the currently selected cell, you must resort to using macros. The following macro will return the value of the cell selected at the time it is run:

```
Public Function CurrentCell() As String
    Application.Volatile
    CurrentCell = ActiveCell.Address
End Function
```

> The inclusion of the Application.Volatile method means that every time the worksheet is recalculated, this function (macro) is again run. To use the macro you can place the following in any cell desired, including `A1:=CurrentCell`
> You should note that this macro doesn't result in the contents of A1 changing every time you move to a different cell. Again, the contents of A1 will change only when the workbook is recalculated, either by changing something in the worksheet or by pressing F9.
>
> If, instead, you need to have a "real-time" version that automatically updates A1 as the selected cell is changed, you can follow these steps:
>
> Display the VBA Editor by pressing Alt+F11.
> In the Project window, at the left side of the Editor, double-click on the name of the worksheet you are using. (You may need to first open the VBAProject folder, and then open the Microsoft Excel Objects folder under it.)
> In the code window for the worksheet, click on the Object drop-down list and choose Worksheet. When you do, the Procedure should change to `SelectionChange`, and the framework for the event handler should appear in the code window.
> Change the event handler so it appears as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Range("A1").Value = ActiveCell.Address
End Sub
```

> Close the VBA Editor.
> Now, as you move about this single sheet, the contents of A1 should be constantly updated to reflect your location.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any excel function/formula which gives the address of active cell in the manner that you are expecting.

However, there is a workaround to this, which you need to try.

Try to write a event macro which will fetch the address of the cell clicked (current cell) and which will then update a specific cell with that address. Your formula can then pick up the pasted address from that specific cell and use it in the formula.

Give it a try , it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rajesh. Yes, that should work, but I was looking for a formula, which would not require VBA, but apparently none exists. The closest I've been able to come is =INDIRECT(CELL("ADDRESS")) but that doesn't refresh automatically; it requires pressing F9 or some other action that causes a recalc. Too bad MS didn't include a simple function such as =ACTIVECELL().

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, give it a try.

```
Sub Solution()
    Dim Here As String
    Here$ = ActiveCell.Address
    ' works from cell b19 to B699
    If Here$ <= Range("B18").Address Or Here$ >= Range("B700").Address Then
        Range("A3") = "No"
    Else
        Range("A3") = Here$
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you can add a macro button or use as Worksheet SheetSelectionChange option.